# Firebase Fetch data from database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for User authentication and using Real time Database as well. I want to loop thru my Real time database after the user logs in using User Authentication.

If I change anything in the real time database. Following event will trigger. But my question is how do I loop through the users list without any changes in the Database? Is it possible?

```
userDB.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for user in snapshot.children{

            print(" user \(user) ")
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(" error \(error.localizedDescription) ")
    }
```

Comment: That block of code will loop through the user list regardless of a change in the database. Do you mind providing more context to the problem?

Comment: Thanks @PeterTao. I have not made any changes in the real time database. Events like child added, child removed, change etc will only work if we make any chances in the DB. My question is how do I loop through any object tree (in my case it's "users") without "Change" or "ChildAdded" or "ChildRemoved" realtime methods.

Comment: Of course @TechBee - happy to help. I might be misunderstanding the question. In the block of code above, aren't we looping through the users list without any changes in the Database? We call the database once and fetch the value of data at the location. "Change", "ChildAdded", nor "ChildRemoved" were used.

Comment: Thanks @PeterTao. The above code fires only if there is any "change" in the database. For example I have one user john. The validation is done via Authentication. On successful user credential you get firebase user as a callback which has a uid property. I have mapped that property in "Users" table in real time database. How do I do that? Since there is no change in the "Users" table.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @TechBee. The part I am trying to wrap my head around is how observeSingleEvent is called when there is a change in the database?

Comment: Hey @PeterTao it's resolved for now. Have a look here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events